# e.Row.RowState is Unchanged in ColumnChanged event

Tags: c#, datatable

I put a breakpoint in an event handler for a DataTable:

```
void DataTable_ColumnChanged(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{

}
```

When a value has changed and this event fires I expect that the e.Row.RowState is Modified, however it is always Unchanged. Is this by design?? It's really annoying, and makes no sense.

What I want to do is, whenever a certian column value has changed in the DataTable, I want to get all the rows that have been modified since last time AcceptChanges was called. So I want to filter on the rows with RowState == DataRowState.Modified, but this is never true.

Comment: What do you want to be done ?

Comment: Why is it annoying when you're in the changed-event anyway? You could handle the `RowChanging` event instead.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, but I want to handle this on a specific column. I don't get why the RowState shouldn't be updated in the ColumnChanged event as well?

Comment: @André: because that change is already accepted at this point. You can access the original value anyway if you want: `e.Row["columnname", DataRowVersion.Original]`

Comment: @TimSchmelter In that case I have to do it another way. I thought the changes was accepted only when you manually called AcceptChanges()